# Incorrect Array length and array element when saving a JSON object key

Tags: javascript, json, web-api-testing, chakram

I have an API with a JSON Array of objects response like this

```
[
   {
     person_id:"12212",
     person_name:"some name",
     deptt : "dept-1"
   },
   { 
     person_id: "12211",
     person_name: "some name 2"
     deptt : "dept-2"
    },

]
```

I am trying to save the values of person_id in an array but the values are not getting saved correctly and so the array length is coming incorrect.

Since I'm using Chakram, this is what I'm currently doing

```
it('gets person id in array',()=>{
  let array_ids =[];
  let count=0;
    return response.then((api_response)=>{
     for(var i=1;i<api_response.body.length;i++){
       //this is correctly printing the person id of response
       console.log('Person ids are ==>'+api_response.body[i].person_id);
       count++;

       //this is not working
       array_ids = api_response.body[i].person_id;
}
      console.log('Count is '+count) //prints correct number
      console.log('Array length '+array_ids.length) //prints incorrect length - sometimes 11, sometimes 12
});
});
```

I want to know why is this happening? Is

```
array_ids = api_response.body[i].person_id
```

an incorrect way of getting/assigning elements in array?

Comment: why are you using chakram?you can just do it normal ways instead.

Comment: My API framework is built in Chakram. This is something that I want to do as a part of a test case assertion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, there is a correction in your code. You're not pushing IDs into an array but you're assigning a new value of IDs every time.

```
it('gets person id in array',()=>{
  let array_ids =[];
  let count=0;
    return response.then((api_response)=>{
     for(var i=1;i<api_response.body.length;i++){
       //this is correctly printing the person id of response
       console.log('Person ids are ==>'+api_response.body[i].person_id);
       count++;

       //this is not working
       array_ids.push(api_response.body[i].person_id); //update
}
      console.log('Count is '+count) //prints correct number
      console.log('Array length '+array_ids.length) //prints incorrect length - sometimes 11, sometimes 12
});
});
```

Comment: You should explain what you changed and why.

Comment: @demouser123 In my opinion code-only answers aren't very helpful (giving a fish vs teaching to fish). Besides, I commented and planned on watching and removing my vote if it was edited.

Answer (score 2):

You  need to push ids into array

```
array_ids.push(api_response.body[i].person_id);
```

You can use `Array.prototype.map()`

```
let array_ids = api_response.body.map(obj => obj.person_id);
let count = array_ids.length;
```